# VMWare failed in buildig kernel modules (ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: kernel, vmware, 13.10

I've tried to install vmware workstation and it requires build modules, but it failed and I have applies patches:

```
cd /tmp
curl -O http://pkgbuild.com/git/aur-mirror.git/plain/vmware-patch/vmblock-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
curl -O http://pkgbuild.com/git/aur-mirror.git/plain/vmware-patch/vmnet-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xvf vmblock.tar
tar -xvf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmblock-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-9.0.2-5.0.2-3.10.patch
tar -cf vmblock.tar vmblock-only
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmblock-only
rm -r vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Then I got error again (grep error):

```
vmblock-only/linux/file.c:240:4: error: unknown field ‘readdir’ specified in initializer
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 13.10 beta1 (Ubuntu GNOME) on all of my machines with the recently-released Workstation 10 version.  It doesn't need any patches installed, and I told some people at  VMware that next Spring, only 12.04 LTS, 13.10, and 14.04 will be supported anyway (since they have historically had no support for the latest few Ubuntu versions).  Hopefully, Saucy+1 will work without patches as well.

Workstation 10 can also control vCenter and ESXi, which means no more running a Windows VM just to control them.  They now also include the VIX API, ovftool, and other libraries and CLI utilities.